# Process manager in user space

Tags: open-source, software-development, programming, unix

As a developer I'm working on a multi-process/service application. I'm looking for a tool, that can start/stop, perhaps monitor my services in the user space.

I found process monitoring tools, but all seem to be targeting the OS level. Monit e.g. might be good for my usecase, but it seems still a bit heavyweight. So is systemd.

Expected functionality:

- give a tool to developers to manage all the application processes they work on
- ideally store script in `git` with the application source code (this is not a must)
- list services in a config file
- `mytool all start` -> start all services within project root e.g. `/home/myname/workspace/project`
- create PID file for each service
- redirect stdout to a log file
- `mytool foo stop` or `mytool foobar restart`
- optinally: continue to run as a daemon, and be able to monitor / alert for dead processes with some rules

So basically what the services command does in Ubuntu, but manage simple user space command.

Answer (score 1):

http://lxinitd.tp23.org/ might fit that purpose.
It was designed it as an alternative for systemd for use in LXC containers.  It has simple service management, when run as `/sbin/init` it reads just `/etc/rc.local` with a list of services.
It can be run as a user space application using a different configuration file.  It only starts & restarts failed services, it monitors their pids, (either child's pid or reading a pid file) if they are killed restarts them.

e.g. create a script like this and execute it

```
#!/bin/lxinitd

service /run/somed.pid /sbin/somed
service /run/nginx.pid /sbin/nginx
```